# Symfony2 form builder add field between fields

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form builder object that I am adding fields to.  How do I added a field between 2 existing fields:

```
$formBuilder->add('name',...)
            ->add('phone',...);

//Somehow here add an 'email' field between the 'name' and 'phone' field

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```

Comment: Was your $formBuilder  created with $this->createFormBuilder($entity);  ? Does your $entity feature an email field?

Comment: If you are looking for an 'addAfter' or 'addBefore' or 'addAt' method, I think that the FormBuilder does not feature one. The FormBuilder stores field info in a private array and you can't modify it directly

Comment: Can you explain why you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order by rendering the form in parts with twig.

```
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form_row(form.email) }}
{{ form_row(form.phone) }}
```